# Issue Running software-properties-gtk: D-Bus Errors on Ubuntu

Tags: dbus, ubuntu-22.04

I'm encountering an issue with running `software-properties-gtk` on my Ubuntu system. Here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
kkaletka@kkaletka:~$ software-properties-gtk 
Error: cannot parse D-BUS name from exception: Could not activate remote peer: unit failed.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: The name does not have an owner

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 210, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: Could not activate remote peer: unit failed.
```

Steps I've already tried include:

1. Checking the D-Bus service status with `systemctl status dbus`, which shows the service is active and running.
2. Updating the system using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
3. Reinstalling `software-properties-gtk` using `sudo apt remove --purge software-properties-gtk` and then `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk`.
4. Restarting the NetworkManager service with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`.
5. Checking system logs for more detailed error information.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!